# Lag after setting text in OnTextChanged()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

Below is an example that replicates my lagging problem. Once I set the text on the EditTextView it takes at least 1.5 seconds for the user to be allowed to input another character.

```
    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String amount = s.toString();

            if( !amount.equals(current )) {
                amountEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                amountEditText.setText(s);
                Selection.setSelection(amountEditText.getText(), amountEditText.getText().length());
                amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

I've searched around and have not found a solution.

Comment: Please check this link. It might help you
https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified that the issue was coming from the textView.setText() call.

The solution was to not use setText(), instead use the Editable that is provided to you in the onTextChanged callback.

I tried to use the Editable before, however i couldn't get it working with inputs such as "$12,000".

This was due to having InputFilters still attached to the Editable.

Regards,
Scott.

Answer (score 0):

It lags because you remove and then readd your listener.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be trying to select the text inside the EditText. To do so, simply set `editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);` or `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` in xml. Then remove the entire TextChangedListener from your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to me it is most probably because of trying to remove (`amountEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);`) and add (`amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);`) the Text Change Listener every time. I would recommend you to replace your code without those adding and removal.

Hope this helped.